# Definition of Iwahori subgroup independently of the Bruhat-Tits building

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, p-adic-numbers

Let $G$ be the points of a connected, semisimple algebraic group over a $p$-adic field $k$.  To make life easy, let's assume the underlying group scheme is simply connected.  The Bruhat-Tits building $\mathscr B$ of $G$ can be constructed from a valued root datum of $G$.  An Iwahori subgroup $B$ of $G$ is defined to be a stabilizer of a chamber in $\mathscr B$.

I know that if the Iwahori subgroup $B$ of $G$ is already given, as well as the normalizer $N$ of a maximal split torus of $G$ in good position relative to $B$, then $\mathscr B$ can be constructed from the BN-pair $(G,B,N)$.  This is explained in the first part of Bruhat-Tits article *Groupes reductifs sur un corps locale I*.

Is it possible to construct the Iwahori subgroup independently of the Bruhat-Tits building?  I would like to approach Bruhat-Tits theory from this point of view, first defining the Iwahori subgroup, then the building.

I know that if (and only if) $G$ is quasi-split to split over an unramified extension of $k$, there is a smooth group scheme $\mathscr G$ over $\mathcal O_k$ such that $G = \mathscr G(k)$ and $\mathscr G(\mathcal O_k)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G$, and then the Iwahori subgroup $B$ of $G$ can be defined as the preimage of a Borel subgroup of $\mathscr G(\mathcal O_k/\mathfrak p_k)$ under the projection $\mathscr G(\mathcal O_k) \rightarrow \mathscr G(\mathcal O_k/\mathfrak p_k)$.  But I think proving this requires Bruhat-Tits theory.

Comment: I _think_ that one can saw something like:  the Iwahori is a maximal pro-$p$ subgroup.  This might not be literally true if one has non-trivial $p$-torsion in the $\Omega$-group, though.

Comment: @LSpice probably you want the normalizer of the maximal pro-$p$ subgroup.

Comment: [Schneider and Stuhler - Representation theory and sheaves on the Bruhat–Tits building](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1997__85__97_0) do something like what you propose, but they define the building in terms of *all* the parahoric subgroups, not just the Iwahori.

Comment: @WillSawin, you are [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364154/definition-of-iwahori-subgroup-independently-of-the-bruhat-tits-building#comment918955_364154); I was [describing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364154/definition-of-iwahori-subgroup-independently-of-the-bruhat-tits-building#comment918954_364154) something closer to the unipotent radical of the Iwahori.

Comment: I don't think the last claim requires Bruhat-Tits theory. You could instead check that quasi-split groups are classified by maps from the Galois group into the automorphisms of the Dynkin diagram (= automorphisms of the pair of a group and the Borel, modulo the Borel), and then observe that each unramified such map corresponds to a map from $\pi_1(\mathcal O_k)$ to the automorphisms and therefore to a group scheme.

Comment: By the way, do think carefully about whether your order of definition is the right one.  If you're doing it because you find the definition of the building complicated and would like to avoid it, (1) you're in good company, but (2) it might be a good idea to bite that bullet and just learn what you need about the building, while knowing that (3) you can do an awful lot understanding how the building *behaves* without going into every detail of how it's *defined*.

Comment: One introduction that is much friendlier than BT itself is [Yu - Bruhat–Tits theory and buildings](http://www.ams.org/books/fim/026/02).

Comment: I understand very well the desire to re-order and simplify the logic in this situation. After trying and failing for a few years, I went so far as to write a book about _classical_ groups and buildings... In fact, after doing so, I realized that _some_ things could be simplified. But I think not the relation between affine and spherical buildings.